# ggplot : How to use column names as x-axis label and the values as y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can't find a way to fix this!

I want to plot a data frame which contains 4 columns it looks like this :

| Species | Mean for today | Mean RCP26 | Mean RCP85 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.567 | 0.765 | 0.342 |
| 2 | 0.987 | 0.543 | 0.001 |
| 3 | 0.456 | 0.876 | 0.54 |

Now I want to plot the col names as the x-axis labels and the corresponding values above them. The species should have a color code in the legend. In the end I hope to get a line diagramm which shows the development from today to rcp85.

I'm trying for hours now using ggplot but I cant find a way to realize it. Would be really glad to get some help.

Comment: Please display your data in a way that can make it easier for respondents to use.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also used `tidyr` to pivot the table.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:4, names_to = "indicators", values_to = "values") %>% 
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = indicators, y = values, color = as.factor(Species), group = Species)) +
    geom_point()
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to pivot your data first, this is achieved by `gather`, also you need the `group` aesthetic to get a line with a discrete x axis

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
    
df %>% 
gather(var, val , -Species) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = var, y = val, color = as.factor(Species), group = as.factor(Species)))+
geom_line()
```

Comment: Development on gather() is complete, and for new code we recommend switching to pivot_longer(). <https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html>